# How to import custom json module instead of the default in python 2.7?

Tags: python, json

Assuming my directory structure is:

```
C:\Scripts\myscript.py
C:\Scripts\customjson\json.py
```

The myscript.py python script has at the top:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]), 'customjson'))
import json
```

The thing is, I have a "customjson" folder that contains a json.py that I want to use instead of the default json package that Python 2.7 comes with. How do I make it so that the script uses "customjson" instead of the standard json?

Comment: Why do you insist on calling your version 'json' too?

Comment: Your module DEFINITELY should have a different name, for God's sake!

Comment: I am trying to use a custom modification to an older version of the json module. If there is an alternative way I should call it, let me know. What changes should I make such that it is a different name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to insert your customjson directory first in `sys.path`:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]), 'customjson'))
import json
```

Comment: Renaming is still the best idea though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
import sys
_orig_path = sys.path
sys.path = ["C:\Scripts\customjson"]
import json
sys.path = _orig_path
```

But, of course, that code wouldn't be portable. To make it portable, you could use:

```
import sys, os
_orig_path = sys.path
sys.path = [
    os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "customjson")),
]
import json
sys.path = _orig_path
```

Or, you could rename `json.py` to, for example, `json2.py`. And then import it:

```
import json2
```

or, if you absolutely need it to be named `json`:

```
import json2 as json
```

..yeah, the second one looks better, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I say: Make your `customjson` folder a [package](http://www.python.org/doc/essays/packages.html).

It's easy:

1. Create a file named `__init__.py` in your customjson folder. The file can be empty if you don't want anything special defined at the package level.
2. Change your `import` statement to refer to the module within the package (i.e. `import customjson.json`).
3. Change your references to the module to use the full path (customjson.json.whatever), or instead further change your `import` statement to include as `as` clause (`import customjson.json as json`). If you're using `from ... import ...` syntax, this is unnecessary. While using an `as` clause may be easier than rewriting your accesses, it may confusing any other programmer who reads your code and expects it to be using the standard json module.

Given the folder layout you describe in the question, you won't need to mess around with the module search path at all if you go this route, since the running script's current folder is always included in the path and that's where the customjson package is located.